# Flutter - does google_maps_flutter make scrolling janky?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a fairly simple screen, which is a Stateless widget. At the top of the screen I have an image, below that a title, below that a subtitle, below that a description, and below all these a google_maps_flutter Map with 3 markers, and 2 polylines. Below the map I have a Button, and a short call to action, but that's irrelevant.

The problem is that the embedded Map is making the scrolling a bit janky - not end of the world janky, but making the user notice janky. If I remove the map everything is really smooth. I've been searching everywhere, but I couldn't find anyone having this issue before. I also rewrote this screen from a Statefull widget to a Stateless one but to no avail. I also rewrote the Map widget from Stateful to Stateless, but no change.

[image: My map implementation]

My Map Widget

[image: Widget tree of above mentioned screen]

Widget tree of above mentioned screen

I have the map on another screen as well, that has the same problem, the common denominator between the two is the SingleChildScrollView - could that be the problem with the Map?

Also the issue is on a real USB connected device (Samsung Galaxy A23 with 8gb ram) - I don't think the device causes the problem, but I might be wrong.

If someone knows what's the solution for this, please tell me, or if it's a known problem I'd like to know that too.